# calling an api request multiple times sequentially using redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I need to call an API request (with different request payloads) multiple times in my reactjs application. But, I don't want to call these multiple requests at the same time and I want to wait till one is completed and then another is called so that they are called sequentially. How can I do this using redux-saga?

Here is how I've impletemented my saga for this specific api, but I don't know how to modify it to work in the way I explained above:

```
export function* fetchChartData(action) {
    const call = Effect.call;
    const put = Effect.put;
    try {
        const response = yield call(chartApi.GetCharts, action.payload)
        yield put({
            type: ActionChartDataType.GET_CHART_DATA_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data.data
        })
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

export function* getAllCharts() {
    yield takeEvery(ActionChartDataType.GET_CHART_DATA_START, fetchChartData)
}
```

In fact, I need to have the action of GET_CHART_DATA_SUCCESS and then call the other GET_CHART_DATA_START. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: So you want to throttle the `chartApi.GetCharts` to have only one active request no matter how many times you call it in a certain time?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I want to have one active request at a certain time and other requests get called whenever the previous request gets the response so that they are called one by one sequetially.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to group a promise returning function in the way you describe:

```js
const group = (promiseFunction) => {
  let promise = Promise.resolve();
  return (...args) => {
    promise = promise
      .catch(() => 'ignore')
      .then(() => promiseFunction(...args));
    return promise;
  };
};

//a helper that returns a promise that resolves in one second
const later = (value) =>
  new Promise((r) => setTimeout(() => r(value), 1000));
//promise returning function that returns passed argument a second later
const promiseFn = (value) => {
  console.log('promiseFn called with', value);
  return later(value).then((r) =>
    r === 3 ? Promise.reject(r) : r
  );
};
//grouped primiseFn
const groupedPromiseFn = group(promiseFn);
//test calling the grouped promise function
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(
  (value) =>
    console.log('calling grouped with', value) ||
    groupedPromiseFn(value).then(
      (r) => console.log('resolved with:', r),
      (r) => console.log('rejected with:', r)
    )
);
```

You can use `group` to have `chartApi.GetCharts` behave in the way you want:

```
const groupedGetCharts = group(chartApi.GetCharts)
//later in your code:
const response = yield call(groupedGetCharts, action.payload)
```